# QGIS flagging shapefiles as 'invalid data source'

Tags: qgis, shapefile, invalid-data, files

I've downloaded some shapefiles (zipped) to my C drive for use in QGIS - however it can't seem to find them when I add a vector layer from the web browser, they simply don't appear. When I try to open the shapefiles directly via *open with > QGIS*, it tells me the data source is invalid.

Strangely, the shapefiles *do* open if I save the zip folders on my company's cloud - so I don't think it's a problem with the files themselves, rather where/how they are stored. I need to have them stored separately on my own machine.

I'm using QGIS 3.34.1.

Does anyone have any pointers or a fix?

Comment: Try dragging and dropping them into the map.

Comment: You unzipped the files, didn't you?

Comment: Are you dragging a file or a URL pointing at a file?